# How can I make a custom validation attribute in C# which validates if an `IEnumerable` contains distinct values?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes

I want to be able to use the attribute in a `ASP.NET Core Web API` to validate properties in payload objects. Here's an example of how I would want it to work.

```
public class Payload
{
    [DistinctValues]
    public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

From what I've seen, the custom attribute should inherit `ValidationAttribute` and override the `IsValid` method. Here's what I've got so far. I don't know how to create the validation logic.

```
public class DistinctValuesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //validation logic here
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //validation logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem ? Why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Are you actually asking how to check if a collection contains no duplicates?

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't know how to write the validation logic

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes, that's what I'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the previous answer, I managed to find a solution for what I needed.

```
public class DistinctValuesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public DistinctValuesAttribute()
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"The collection should contain distinct values";
        }

        public DistinctValuesAttribute(string errorMessage)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var values = value as IEnumerable<object>;

            if (values != null && values.Any())
            {
                return values.Distinct().Count() == values.Count();
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `object` is one way to support generic. However, when perform a comparison with the class instance, it will compare by reference. Even though all the values of the properties for different instances are the same, it will still not recognize as duplicare. Thus this requires an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`. And sadly this requires generic attribute which is only achievable in C# 11.

Answer (score 0):

In this `bool IsValid(object value)` method, to find whether the list contains any duplicate value, you can compare the count of distinct values against the total count of values.

```cs
values.Distinct().Count() == values.Count();
```

In this `ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)` method,

When the count of values is not equal (fail validation), you should return an instance of  `ValidationResult`.

For success validation, you should return `ValidationResult.Success`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

public class DistinctValuesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{   
    public DistinctValuesAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"{this.TypeId} contains duplicate value";
    }
    
    public DistinctValuesAttribute(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values = value as IEnumerable<string>;
        
        if (values != null && values.Any())
        {
            return values.Distinct().Count() == values.Count();
        }   
        
        return true;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!IsValid(value))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, new List<string> { this.TypeId.ToString() });
        }
        
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Sample Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/67LrRl)

Comment: I would like it to work for more than only strings. How can that be done?

Comment: @stack_overflow_nickname (nice name btw!) This could be done with the new (C# 11) [generic attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-attributes).

Comment: (thanks!) Unfortunately I only have C# 9 in my project.